# object detection with color

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the tabletop object detector to give the robot a semantic map of the environment it is in.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tabletop_object_detector

I would like to be able to somehow also extract color information about the objects - for example if the robot detects a coca-cola can, the tag of the object should look something like ['can','red','white','metallic'] or ['can','red'] for example.

Does anybody know of a tool that does anything similar, maybe using the object detector positions as a part of the input?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10695/object-detection-with-color/) by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 535 on 2011-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're working on a system that does something like this (for large environments), but it's not released yet.

Until then, you could use the point clouds extracted by your segmenter as a source of data for labeling. For example, you could compute the mean color of the cloud, and then bucket that into "red", "blue", "orange", or whatever. Computing a "can" label could be done using cylinder fitting; computing "metallic" would be quite a bit trickier.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1